# When it is generally preferred to use SORT_IN_TEMPDB=Off when creating index?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, tempdb

I am familiar with the indexing concepts from developer's perspective but new to creating and maintaining indexes.
Most of our indexes are created with `SORT_IN_TEMPDB=On` option, which tells SQL Server to use `tempdb` for the sorting operations involved during the indexing.

Using the `tempdb` for indexing should
speed up the sorting and reduce some IO load from the user database by using tempdb resources instead.

I recently run into an index definition which had `SORT_IN_TEMPDB=Off`, which tells the SQL server to sort in the user database.

Questions:

1. Would not `SORT_IN_TEMPDB=off` slow down the user database because the sorting will be done using user database resources?
2. What factors generally contribute to the decision of using `SORT_IN_TEMPDB=off`?

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188281.aspx) explains this on a quite detail level

Comment: If the doc doesn't answer you questions, post your question to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server.